# Python comprehensions in function calls (PEP 448)

Tags: python, python-3.x, language-lawyer

(This is all on Python 3.5.2)

At the bottom of [PEP 448](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/), I see:

> Unbracketed comprehensions in function calls, such as `f(x for x in it)` , are already valid.

This is intriguing. If I define the following function:

```
def f(a, b, c):
    return a + b + c
```

then that wording makes me think that `f(thing for thing in [1, 2, 3]) == 6`. But actually, I get:

```
>>> f(thing for thing in [1, 2, 3])
TypeError: f() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'b' and 'c'
```

i.e. the whole generator expression passed as `a`.

So what does this sentence in PEP 448 mean? Just that you can pass a generator expression as an argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python allows you to pass a single generator expression to a function you're calling without needing extra parentheses. For instance:

```
foo(x for x in range(10))
```

is mostly equivalent to:

```
genexp = (x for x in range(10)) # parentheses are necessary here
foo(genexp)
```

You do still need the parentheses when defining the generator expression if there are other arguments that you're passing to the function call (e.g. `foo(w, (x for x in range(10)), y, z)`, where the second argument is a generator expression of `x`'s).

The PEP was mentioning in passing that a further extension of the unpacking syntax might be confusing in that context. If a new kind of generator expression `(*x for x in nested)` was legal (it is not part the final PEP, but was being considered for a while), how should `foo(*x for x in nested)` work? Would it be equivalent to `foo((*x for x in nested))` (calling with a single generator expression, that included the new "flattening" `*`), or would it mean `foo(*(x for x in nested))` (which is legal now)?

Answer (score 5):

This statement means only that in **pre-PEP** world `f(x for x in it)` was already valid and passed generator expression as first function argument.

To make your example work, you need to explicitly unpack generator, as shown in PEP examples.

```
f(*(thing for thing in [1, 2, 3]))  # returns 6
```

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is that on line `f(thing for thing in [1, 2, 3])` you are passing only the first argument, which is a generator. Arguments `b` and `c` are missing.

Also, check the following part of the PEP:

> However, it wasn't clear if this was the best behaviour or if it
>   should unpack into the arguments of the call to f . Since this is
>   likely to be confusing and is of only very marginal utility, it is not
>   included in this PEP. Instead, these will throw a SyntaxError and
>   comprehensions with explicit brackets should be used instead.

Answer (score 0):

Actually `f(x for x in it)` is not a new feature that introduced by PEP 448 but by [PEP 289](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/). Noted not all features that discussed in PEP 448 are implemented in Python 3.5. The ["Variations" section](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/#variations) mentioned in the question is not implemented:

> Since this is likely to be confusing and is of only very marginal
>   utility, it is not included in this PEP. Instead, these will throw a
>   `SyntaxError` and comprehensions with explicit brackets should be used
>   instead.